# How to reduce code duplication for ReceiveActor

Tags: c#, .net, akka, akka.net

I have Receive Actor with switchable behaviors, switched by Become() method. To monitor child actors, I have to add Receive< Terminated > call to every state method.

For example, I have to paste it into Ready, Working1 and Working2 methods

```
public class SomeActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public SomeActor()
    {
        // create child actors
        Become(Ready);
    }

    private void Ready()
    {
        Receive<InitMessage>(m =>
        {
            Become(Working1);
        });

        Receive<Terminated>(m =>
        {
            // duplicated termination stuff 
            Become(Terminated);
        });
    }

    private void Working1()
    {
        Receive<InitMessage>(m =>
        {
            Become(Working2);
        });

        Receive<Terminated>(m =>
        {
            // duplicated termination stuff 
            Become(Terminated);
        });
    }

    private void Working2()
    {
        Receive<InitParcerMessage>(m =>
        {
            Become(Working1);
        });

        Receive<Terminated>(m =>
        {
            // duplicated termination stuff 
            Become(Terminated);
        });
    }

    private void Terminated()
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what actually are your trying to achieve. In akka monitoring/watching an actor is a term associated with checking it's aliveness using `Context.Watch(actorRef)`. Please, describe what do you actually want to monitor here.

Comment: You can trigger an event and subscribe all children to it to let them know when you want to process the Terminated method at the end of the Become, in some middle point, etc

Comment: @Zinov you mean simple c# event?

Comment: yes @bonzaster  it should work on that way too, at the end the events are delegate types, so you can make the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a lambda to perform your action, instead you can create a private method that takes a type of `Terminated` as the parameter and use the `MethodGroup` in your `Receive` action.

```
public class SomeActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public SomeActor()
    {
        // create child actors
        Become(Ready);
    }

    private void Ready()
    {
        Receive<InitMessage>(m =>
        {
            Become(Working1);
        });

        ConfigureReceive();
    }

    private void Working1()
    {
        Receive<InitMessage>(m =>
        {
            Become(Working2);
        });

        ConfigureReceive();
    }

    private void Working2()
    {
        Receive<InitParcerMessage>(m =>
        {
            Become(Working1);
        });

        ConfigureReceive();
    }

    private void Terminated()
    {
        // do some stuff
    }

    private void ConfigureReceive()
    {
        // Register Receive actors here
        Receive<Terminated>(p => HandleTermination(p));
    }

    // Here's our method to perform the same job with our Terminated parameter
    private void HandleTermination(Terminated termination)
    {
        // Call our Become method
        Become(Terminated);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, but anyway I have to add this _Receive<Terminated>(HandleTermination);_  everywhere. Just imagine, that I want to handle more then one message types in this way, it will be much more duplicated lines

Comment: I've updated the code snippet. You'll have to have some code duplication somewhere, but this update trims it down to keep your `Receive` in a method so you only have to update code in one place.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the answer